# Find all integers $a$ and $b$, such that $\frac{a^b + 1}{b^a + 1}$ an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've recently been attempting to solve the following problem and made some initial progress. However, im not able to progress any further, any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers. For which values of $a$ and $b$ is the quotient $\frac{a^b + 1}{b^a + 1}$ an integer?

Thus far I have found that when $b=1$, then $\frac{a^b + 1}{b^a + 1}$ is an integer for all odd positive integers $a$. Likewise, the quotient is an integer when $a=b$ and when $(a,b)=(2,4)$ and $(a,b)=(4,2)$.

I haven't yet been able to find any more solutions and I also have no ideas on how I can prove that there are no more solutions, other than the ones given.

Comment: A similar question [Determine all the pairs  of a prime number  and a positive integer  for which 
 is an integer](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h472954)

Comment: This appears to be [a G research December puzzle](https://www.gresearch.co.uk/news/g-research-december-maths-puzzle/), and it looks hard: The [$a=2$ case](http://oeis.org/A247220) is an open problem from at least year 2014 (or earlier).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you got this problem. It seems to me that it is either impossible or very difficult to get a complete answer.

In particular, your claim that "there are no more solutions" is wrong.

As an example: $a = 2$ and $b = 386$.

---

There are other families of examples: take any odd $a$ and take $b = a^n$, where $n$ divides $a^{n - 1}$ (e.g. $n = a^k$ for some $k$).

Comment: I claimed that I was unable to find any more solutions, as opposed to there being no more. But thank you for showing that particular solution, I had not found that.

Comment: FYI: even for $a = 2$ there are more: $b = 20136, 59140, 373164544$. See http://oeis.org/search?q=386%2C+20136&language=english&go=Search

Comment: Also, for $a = 3$ there are $b = 27, 19683$. This is not yet on OEIS.

Answer (score 3):

There are infinitely many solutions of the following form.

If $p$ is an odd positive integer and $k = p^{p^r}$, then $k^p+1 = p^{p^{r+1}}+1$ divides $p^k+1 = p^{p^{p^r}}+1$.  This is because
$x+1$ divides $x^p+1$.

Comment: I don't know why, but I already gave this example (in a more general form) in my answer.